# Show image in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to show a saved image in SQL Server but it gives me an error that says "parameter is not valid".

```
        While oDataReader.Read()
            TextBox1.Text = oDataReader("nombre")
            Dim imagenbyte As Byte()
            imagenbyte = oDataReader("imagen")
            Dim mStream As New IO.MemoryStream()
            mStream.Write(imagenbyte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imagenbyte.Length))
            Dim bm As Bitmap = New Bitmap(mStream, True)
            PictureBox1.Image = bm

        End While
```

Comment: "Gives error" is not a helpful. Read this and learn how to write a [mcve]

Comment: I also think a lot of the code should be outside the While loop.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(imagenbyte.Length)` - Why??? Just... Why???? `imagenbyte.Length` _**already is**_ an `Int32`! (also known as `Integer`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consolidate that code down to this:

```
While oDataReader.Read()
    TextBox1.Text = oDataReader("nombre")
    Dim mStream As New IO.MemoryStream(oDataReader("imagen"))
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(mStream)
End While
```

The main fix here is using `Image` instead of `Bitmap`. And if you know you'll only have one record, you should change `While` to `If`. If you might have more than one record, you need to completely re-think some things in your user interface.

Comment: `If oDataReader.Read() Then`

Comment: @LarsTech Probably. But I suspect reading the image isn't the only problem here. There may well be more than one record to deal with and the OP will also need to figure out how to use a grid, flowlayoutpanel, or similar. One step at a time.

Comment: @LarsTech with the "while", it would end up with the last image while the "if" would end up with the first. This assume there can be more than one returned image.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm going to make changes. And part of that code does not work the MemoryStream

Comment: @the_lotus Based on the TextBox and the PictureBox and the OP stating "I'm trying to show a saved image", clearly the "intent" of the code is to show only one string and one image.  The database query call should be filtering the data down to one record, hence, the if-condition would be more appropriate.

Comment: @LarsTech I agree